# How to use Matlab to transfer learning using pre-trained CIFAR-10 network?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify a set of images using transfer learning approach. All of the tutorials I came across used Alexnet to fine tune and transfer learning. However, I am trying to use a less complicated model like CIFAR-10. I went through this [Matlab Tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-using-deep-learning.html). At the point where they start transfer learning, they used Matlab's sample data. They loaded the ground truth data in a table,

`%Load the ground truth data
data = load('stopSignsAndCars.mat', 'stopSignsAndCars');
stopSignsAndCars = data.stopSignsAndCars;`

The table contains the image filename and ROI labels for stop signs, car fronts, and rears. Each ROI label is a bounding box around objects of interest within an image. Then they kept only labels for stop signs.

What should I do, if I want to use my own images for this network in a similar approach used for Alexnet,

```
net=alexnet;
layersTransfer = net.Layers(1:end-3);


readAllDir=uigetdir('','Select All directory to read scaled image files');
AllSample=imageDatastore(readAllDir, 'IncludeSubfolders', true, 'LabelSource','foldernames');
```

By the similar approach, I mean making the 'imageDatastore' for all the labelled images and using them to train the network.